# Getting region masks from opencv implementation of selective search algorithm

Tags: opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am trying to generate region proposals for training a segmentation model. I saw the OpenCV implementation :

```
cv2.ximgproc.segmentation.createSelectiveSearchSegmentation()
```

and this implementation is returning the region proposals as bounding boxes quite well. But based on my understanding of this algorithm, it used Felzenszwalb's graph segmentation as the inital seed and runs colour,size, texture & shape similarity metrics to group regions further.

Is there any way to access the segmentation mask generated after running selective search on Felzenszwalb aglorithm's output in OpenCV?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to visualise the segmentation mask output of selective search, I have added functionality to the OpenCV-contrib (not committed to the original repo ) file & now along with boxes, you also have segmentation masks as output.

In the code, images is a private variable but the masks are stored as points in OpenCV. Therefore in order to retrieve the image masks, I made a few updates in the items being returned in the code.

Here is the code for reference :
https://www.kaggle.com/code/vedantj/selective-search/notebook